# Swift Version NativeScript

Tags: ios, swift, vue.js, cocoapods, nativescript

Using NativeScript how can I run a project under iOS? I get these messages when I run `tns run iOS --bundle`

```
Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
Copying template files...
Platform ios successfully added. v4.2.0
Executing before-shouldPrepare hook from /Users/Zian/Documents/Projects/NativeScript/Hybrid/hooks/before-shouldPrepare/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Preparing project...
Executing before-prepareJSApp hook from /Users/Zian/Documents/Projects/NativeScript/Hybrid/hooks/before-prepareJSApp/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Installing pods...
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Socket.IO-Client-Swift (11.1.3)
Installing StarscreamSocketIO (8.0.7)
Installing Toaster (2.0.4)
[!] Unable to determine Swift version for the following pods:

- `Socket.IO-Client-Swift` does not specify a Swift version and none of the targets (`Hybrid`) integrating it have the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute set. Please contact the author or set the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute in at least one of the targets that integrate this pod.
- `StarscreamSocketIO` does not specify a Swift version and none of the targets (`Hybrid`) integrating it have the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute set. Please contact the author or set the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute in at least one of the targets that integrate this pod.
- `Toaster` does not specify a Swift version and none of the targets (`Hybrid`) integrating it have the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute set. Please contact the author or set the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute in at least one of the targets that integrate this pod.
Unable to apply changes on device: 21FFE2BB-EB0D-48E3-A7AD-28CA08DD21E5. Error is: Command pod failed with exit code 1 Error output: 

[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `8.0` on target `Hybrid` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Already did it, thanks

Comment: The message is pretty clear… "Please contact the author **or set the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute in at least one of the targets** that integrate this pod." See the cocoapods documentation for details.

Comment: Make sure your POD repo is upto date and try a clean build that most time fixes the issues.

Comment: @Manoj trying your solution but still no work

Comment: @FauziyyanThafhanRahman please mark answer as accepted if it solved for you, or add another comment with your results.

Answer (score 14):

Just had these same errors and found out downgrading from cocoapods 1.6.0 to 1.5.3 fixed it for me.

```
    sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
    sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.5.3
```

Comment: You can't stick with an outdated version of Cocoapods forever, see my answer below for the real fix.

Comment: have switched from using toaster to toasty and can now upgrade cocoapods as long as no other plugin is still using swift 3

Answer (score 11):

The problem here seems to be Toaster (2.0.4), which appears to have been developed for Swift 3.

I did this in order to resolve the issue:

1. go to the main folder for the nativescript project
2. In your bash shell, do:

   `% export SWIFT_VERSION=3`
3. Then do your usual:

   `% tns build ios --bundle`
4. Then open the project in Xcode:

   % cd platforms/ios

   % Open *.workspace

You'll get a warning about a build error in the pods project and may need to set your development team, but it should work.

Comment: Alternatively, you can include `ENV['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3'` at the top of your `Podfile`.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is with Cocoapods 1.6.x which have different behavior when it comes up to SWIFT_VERSION. Previously it was possible to set the SWIFT_VERSION in post_install hook of the Podfile, but now the `pod install` command fails before even getting to post_install.
The best solution is to use Cocoapod which already has SWIFT_VERSION set, i.e. in case you face the error, try to contact the Pod author.
Meanwhile, as a workaround, you can add a `pre_install` script in your `<path to App_Resources/iOS/Podfile` file with the following content:

```
pre_install do |installer|
    installer.analysis_result.specifications.each do |s|
        if s.name == 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift' || s.name == 'Starscream' || s.name == 'StarscreamSocketIO' || s.name == 'Toaster'
            s.swift_version = '4.2'
        end
    end
end
```

For each of the Pods you can set different Swift version based on their requirements.

Answer (score 4):

I have it fixed with @K Brown's answer.

Was having these errors when running `tns run ios --bundle` 
for `Socket.IO-Client-Swift`, `StarscreamSocketIO` and `Toaster` when both v1.6.0 and v1.5.3 of Cocoapods installed:

```
- `<package name>` does not specify a Swift version and none of the targets 
(`<project name>`) integrating it have the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute set. 
Please contact the author or set the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute in at least one 
of the targets that integrate this pod.
```

Below are the commands used:

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`

`sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.5.3`

`rm -Rf platforms`

`tns install`

`tns run ios --bundle`

Answer (score 2):

### Here is the real fix ! You can't stick with Cocoapods 1.5.3 forever...

Downgrading to `1.5.3` isn't a proper workaround and will not be sustainable in the future. In fact, this error is due to a new behavior introduced in Cocoapods `1.6.0` version, which force developers to set a Swift version to their projects. The goal is in fact to make library developers specify a Swift version in their `podspec`, so that library users don't have to do this manually (thanks to `post_install` scripts for example). You can see [my discussion about this with a Cocoapods maintainer here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8607). I do agree that this behavior is a bit misleading, as we try to set the Swift version in `post_install` script but an error is returned before…

In fact, as I have been told by the maintainer, the correct fix to this issue is to set a Swift version at project level (and therefore not at Pod level). To do this, just add a new `User Defined Setting` in `Build Settings`, with key `SWIFT_VERSION` and value `4.0` (for example, as whatever value should work here if you also set the version at Pod level with `post_install` script).

**Long story short, the fix is to add this key/value :**
[image]

Note that as you're using NativeScript, you may want to set the Swift version by running command `export SWIFT_VERSION=4` in your project folder, before building.

Comment: This will set the SWIFT_VERSION for the whole project. It is possible different Pods to require different SWIFT_VERSION, so setting it this way may lead to failing build.