# Nativescript Algolia iOS Build Fail

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

I am trying to build [nativescript-algolia](https://github.com/arpit2438735/nativescript-algolia) but it fails on iOS. This is the error I am getting:

```
[!] Unable to determine Swift version for the following pods:

- `AlgoliaSearch-Client-Swift` does not specify a Swift version 
and none of the targets (`appname`) integrating it have the 
`SWIFT_VERSION` attribute set. Please contact the author
or set the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute in at least one of the 
targets that integrate this pod.
```

I have tried everything I have seen from Googling this problem. I just can't seem to set the Swift Version correctly.

Comment: https://github.com/arpit2438735/nativescript-algolia/commit/eb547e63de951165147aa245bb34f75a78fba335#diff-5cc01b40f7d75f3e31e978bb37ae2e66

Comment: try to add the platform :ios, '8.0 in podfile

Comment: Already tried that...no luck.

Comment: is it possible for you to create a playground? Add package `nativescript-algolia`

Comment: do you have sample Application ID and API Key to test?

Comment: How would it work on Playground? It depends on special native SDK dependencies

Comment: This should work in playground, as there is an option to add npm package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downgrading to `1.5.3` isn't a proper workaround and will not be sustainable in the future. In fact, this error is due to a new behavior introduced in Cocoapods `1.6.0` version, which force developers to set a Swift version to their projects. The goal is in fact to make library developers specify a Swift version in their `podspec`, so that library users don't have to do this manually (thanks to `post_install` scripts for example). You can see [my discussion about this with a Cocoapods maintainer here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8607). I do agree that this behavior is a bit misleading, as we try to set the Swift version in `post_install` script but an error is returned before…

In fact, as I have been told by the maintainer, the correct fix to this issue is to set a Swift version at project level (and therefore not at Pod level). To do this, just add a new `User Defined Setting` in `Build Settings`, with key `SWIFT_VERSION` and value `4.0` (for example, as whatever value should work here if you also set the version at Pod level with `post_install` script).

**Long story short, the fix is to add this key/value :**
[image]

Note that as you're using NativeScript, you may want to set the Swift version by running command `export SWIFT_VERSION=4` in your project folder, before building.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file named `Podfile` in `App_Resources/iOS` and add the following lines,

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
     end
   end
end
```

Comment: Did you try a clean build?

Answer (score 1):

With the help from the plugin creator I was able to fix this by downgrading my Cocoapods version.

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.5.3
```

References:

https://github.com/arpit2438735/nativescript-algolia/issues/19#issuecomment-472847392

[Swift Version NativeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009550/swift-version-nativescript/54584360#54584360)

Comment: Downgrading Cocoapods version isn't a proper workaround, you will not be able to stick with `1.5.3` version forever. Please see my answer bellow.