# Xcode 10.2 support with the latest NativeScript?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Building an iOS project after using the default NativeScript Advanced Mac OS instructions does not work.

I have a fresh, new macbook, OSX Mojave 10.14.4, with the latest available Xcode Version 10.2 (10E125).

I followed the NativeScript instructions precisely:
https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-os-x

After a few hiccups, I have Android working, but not iOS.

I first started with the issue and solution found here: [Swift Version NativeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009550/swift-version-nativescript/54587142#54587142)

However, after following the steps to downgrade cocoapods from 1.6.0 to 1.5.3, I get errors about Swift 3.0 / 3.1 not being supported and again, a failed build.

After setting up NativeScript using the docs, you see this error:

```
[!] Unable to determine Swift version for the following pods (for each pod):

- `Socket.IO-Client-Swift` does not specify a Swift version and none of the targets (`<my-project>`) integrating it have the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute set. Please contact the author or set the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute in at least one of the targets that integrate this pod.
```

After downgrading cocoapods, you see this error instead (for each pod):

```
error: SWIFT_VERSION '3.1' is unsupported, supported versions are: 4.0, 4.2, 5.0. (in target 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift')
```

I also tried opening the project in Xcode. You immediately see the same error from the command line.

Is there any way for the latest Xcode and the default NativeScript setup to work without any further configuration?

Comment: Of course {N} supports Xcode 10.2 but the issue above is with the plugin. I think setting `SWIFT_VERSION` to 4 might solve your problem.

Comment: Where and how do I do this?

Comment: And when you say that might solve my problem - does it require using the older cocoapods as mentioned in the other stackoverflow article? Or should it work from a brand new default nativescript project?

Comment: Yes, I meant modifying the Swift version from Podfile.

Comment: I'm not an ios developer. Do you have any further information on how to do this?

Comment: Open the issue in plugin's project on GitHub (if it does not yet).

Comment: Try [this](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/legacy-swift-version-when-using-ios-pod/4132/2), instead of 3 use 4 as version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Xcode 10.2 brings Swift 5 and deprecates Swift 3. Plugins that use outdated Swift code won't work.

Solution 1: Downgrade to Xcode 10.1.

Solution 2: Update the nativescript plugins that use Swift 3 pods.

1. Update to the latest `nativescript-vue-devtools`

```sh
npm uninstall nativescript-vue-devtools
npm install --save nativescript-vue-devtools
```

2. Replace the packages `nativescript-socket.io` with `nativescript-socketio`:

```sh
npm uninstall nativescript-socket.io
npm install --save nativescript-socketio
```

3. Replace the packages `nativescript-toast` with `nativescript-toasty`:

```sh
npm uninstall nativescript-toast
npm install --save nativescript-toasty
```

Comment: Solution #2 worked - thank you!

I feel like the docs need to be updated to reflect either of these things, no?

Comment: I am glad it worked. I don't think the docs need to be updated because soon after this issue was discovered, the `nativescript-vue-devtools` and the `vue-cli-template` were fixed. New users will now run into this problem. Old users, well, should be able to find this answer here or in Slack

Comment: @TiagoA. Just for clarity-- new users should NOT run into this problem, right? Hoping that's just a typo above!

Comment: Yes! :) New users will NOT run into this problem.